# How to check different scenarios in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm currently getting 96% of the code coverage and as this is my first test class, dont know how to check for negative case and bulk operations.An help in the code will be helpful.

**Batch**

```
    public class Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversary implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
    {
      String errors = '';
      integer todayday = date.today().day();
      Integer currentmonth = date.today().month();

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
       return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Anniversary__c, NSCHBC__c, Status__c, ID, (SELECT Id, Anniversary__c, OwnerId, ContactId, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, Description, Priority, RecordTypeId, Subject FROM cases order by CreatedDate) from Account WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Anniversary__c) =:todayday AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Anniversary__c ) =: currentmonth');
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
        Id Activation_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Activation Action Plan').getRecordTypeId();
        Id Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Master Action Plan').getRecordTypeId();
        Id NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NSCHBC Action Plan').getRecordTypeId();
        Id Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Total Core Action Plan').getRecordTypeId();

        if(scope.isEmpty()) return;


        Map<Id, Case> clonedCasesMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
        Map<Id, list<Case>> NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap = new Map<Id, list<Case>>();
        for(Account account : scope) {
            // Clone cases on Anniversary
            if(account.cases!=null && account.cases.size() > 0) {
                list<Case> lstCase = new list<Case>();
                for(Case objcase : account.cases){
                    // Fetch only those Cases to be cloned whose Record type is of 
                    if(objcase.RecordTypeId == Activation_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId
                    || objcase.RecordTypeId == Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId
                    || objcase.RecordTypeId ==NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId
                    || objcase.RecordTypeId ==Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId){ 
                        Case cloneCase = new Case();
                        cloneCase  = objcase.clone();
                        clonedCasesMap.put(objcase.Id,cloneCase);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check whether Account is of NSCHBS type
            if(account.NSCHBC__c && account.Status__c == 'Active') {
                NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.put(account.Id, account.cases);
            }
            system.debug('--- NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap --->' + NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap);
        }

        if(!clonedCasesMap.isEmpty()) {
            Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(clonedCasesMap.values(), false);
            Integer index = 0;

            for(Database.SaveResult result : srList ) {
                if(!result.isSuccess()) {
                    String errMsg = result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                } 
                index++;
            }
        }

        // create task on cases
        List<Task> taskCreateList = new List<Task>();
        if(!NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.isEmpty()) {
            for(Id accountId : NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.keyset()){
                if(NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.get(accountId) != null && NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.get(accountId).size() > 0) {
                    for(Case caseObj : NSCHBCAccountToCasesMap.get(accountId)) {
                        Task createTask = new Task();
                        createTask.subject = 'QCR Anniversary';
                        createTask.ActivityDate = caseObj.Anniversary__c + 330;
                        createTask.OwnerId = caseObj.OwnerId;
                        taskCreateList.add(createTask);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // check for task list is empty or not
        if(!taskCreateList.isEmpty()) {
            // insert task list Of Task which were cloned  
            Database.SaveResult[] srListTask = Database.insert(taskCreateList, false);
            Integer indexTask = 0;
            System.debug('Created Task is' +srListTask);

            for(Database.SaveResult resultTask : srListTask ) {
                if(!resultTask.isSuccess()) {
                    String errMsgTask = resultTask.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                } 
                indexTask++;
            } 
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

**Test**

```
   @isTest
    private class Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversaryTest {

   static testmethod void test() {

   Account objAcc = new Account ();
   objAcc.name = 'TestClass';
   objAcc.Anniversary__c = date.today();
   objAcc.NSCHBC__c=true;
   objAcc.Status__c='Active';
   insert objAcc;

   Id Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Total Core Action Plan').getRecordTypeId();
   Case objCase = new Case();
   objCase.AccountId = objAcc.Id;
   objCase.RecordTypeId=Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId;
   insert objCase;


   Task objTask = new Task();
   ObjTask.WhatId = ObjCase.Id;
   insert objTask;


   Test.startTest();
   Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversary c = new  Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversary();
   Database.executeBatch(c);
   Test.stopTest();

   // Verify merchandise items got deleted 
   Integer i = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Case];
   System.assertEquals(i, 2);

   Integer j = [select count() from Task];
   system.assertEquals(j,2);

}
```

}

Comment: Can you give more details -as in what is not being covered?

Comment: Examine the batch class and create multiple test methods that ensure the main branches of the batchable class are executed by setting up the appropriate data. Don't focus on coverage, focus on confirming the behaviour of the batchable and you'll get the coverage as a side-effect.

Comment: Want quick help in code as i'm not able to proceed

Comment: Does start() method return records?